# Why doesn't `my $x = if (0) {1} else {2}` work?

Tags: perl, if-statement, expression

In perl, `$x = if (0) {1} else {2}` does not work.

```
$ perl -E'$x = if (0) {1} else {2}'
syntax error at -e line 1, near "= if"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This makes sense, because `if` conditionals are not expressions in Perl. They're flow control.

But then

```
my $x = do { if (0) {1} else {2} };
```

Does work! How come a `do BLOCK` can accept an `if` conditional? But assignment can not? It would seem in the above the flow control must either

- know it's context in a `do BLOCK`
- always act as an expression, but have that syntax disallowed by the parser.

Moreover given the simple facts above, what is the right way to describe an if-conditional that behaves like that? Is it an expression with a value? Is it flow-control construct that has no value after evaluation?

And, lastly, what modifications would have to be made to assignment to have it accept an `if` condition like a `do BLOCK`.

Comment: it's just not allowed syntax.  every statement has context, and a do block supplies context, just like if the statement were the last in a subroutine.

I don't see any benefit to allowing `$x = if ...`, seems unlikely to fly.  if you want arbitrary statements in an expression, do blocks already exist for that.

Comment: The over-arching design is that perl has keywords that only are meaningful in certain contexts, and `if` is one of them - it can be only the start of a statement or a statement modifier, and neither of those are valid directly after an `=`. This is a parser distinction first and foremost.

Comment: Beyond that, the consideration of "what an if statement returns" is not always intuitive, so while you can find that out by putting it in a do block or the last statement of a subroutine, it's not something that should be encouraged to be used as a value. In fact it [commonly leads to bugs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Freenode::ConditionalImplicitReturn).

Comment: @Grinnz if you want to answer with that, I'll accept.

Comment: The [do BLOCK](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) behavior is clear -- "_Returns the value of the last command..._". So it evaluates the condition under `if` and then executes code in the corresponding branch ... and returns the value of the last thing (that returned a value).  And `2` is a fine expression to return a value from.  So no mystery?

Comment: @zdim but the do-block ends with statement-level control flow, not with an expression (or whatever a "command" is). I consider that example to have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @amon well yes, and I don't see such use as good practice.  But the execution path is clear and we do end up with a "last statement" (that returns), and `do` promises to return _that_.  May be an abuse but  it appears clear what one gets out of it. (That is, unless the `if-else` _doesn't produce a value_ -- which is in general possible, so thus it may well be exactly UB as you say.  However, `do` doesn't take a `return` either ...it's a little particular device, no?)

Comment: perl syntax distinguishes between expressions and statements, like many languages.  though different languages have different lines between them; assignment is a statement in some languages, for example.  but as a completely separate issue, in perl, statements do have return values (disregarding what may be documented or not); for instance, a block "statement" returns the value of its last statement; an if or unless that does not enter a block returns the value of the tested expression, while one that enters a block returns the value of the block; a for returns nothing.

Comment: If a block is a statement that returns a value, then what is an expression in to perl? How would one intuit that the ternary is an expression and not a statement that returns a value? I thought the ternary was an expression *because* it returned it a value.

Comment: Aiui...  A statement is a grammatical unit that ➊ Signals to user and `perl` that its primary purpose in life is to have a side effect ➋ (At least notionally) returns a value that may sometimes be of use ➌ Suggests to `perl` there's no need to complain if the value is dropped on the floor.  An expression ➊ Makes no claim about having a side effect ➋ Claims it will produce a useful value  The `perl` grammar constrains where it'll accept an expression vs a statement, and the vocabulary provides particular statement and expression constructs, in order to provide a pleasant overall language.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer and commentary that addresses the question in a matter that brings clarity is Ginnz,

> The over-arching design is that perl has keywords that only are meaningful in certain contexts, and `if` is one of them - it can be only the start of a statement or a statement modifier, and neither of those are valid directly after an `=`. **This is a parser distinction first and foremost.** Beyond that, the consideration of "what an `if` statement returns" is not always intuitive, so while you can find that out by putting it in a do block or the last statement of a subroutine, it's not something that should be encouraged to be used as a value. In fact it [commonly leads to bugs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Freenode::ConditionalImplicitReturn). – Grinnz 11 hours ago

When Ginnz says parser distinction, I interpret that to mean that this isn't much worth pursing as a matter of clarity. What is valid after an `=` is simply not a `if` statement, and there is no real reason for it, except that it's how it is.

- `if` conditional is a statement.
- statement's return values.
- assignment `=` expressly forbids statements on the right because it only accepts things in the expression class.
- a `do BLOCK` can turn a statement into an expression.

Comment: "When Ginnz says parser distinction, I interpret that to mean that this isn't much worth pursing as a matter of clarity." I could say you haven't expressed yourself clearly with that statement. :) Aiui you've misinterpreted "parser distinction" as being specific to `if` but Grinnz didn't mean that. "What is valid after an `=` is simply not a `if` statement" Simply not *any* statement. "there is no real reason for it" I imagine the most people get confused the least if `=` rejects statements on the right (because many statements would do something thoroughly confusing if they were allowed).

Comment: "because many statements would do something thoroughly confusing if they were allowed" - right, like: `my $foo = foreach (@things) { say }` - you could wrap this in a `do {}` sure, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Code inside DO block behaves differently. Perl interprets the code inside the curly brackets and outputs the result of the last command.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    
    use Data::Dumper;
    
    my $x = do { { 1==1 } };
    my $y = do { { 1==0 } };
    print Dumper 1==0;
    print Dumper $x;
    print Dumper $y;
```

Read more about do:
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#do